# How to reference another hostvar variable in an inventory file

Tags: ansible

How can I reference another host's var in the inventory file definition?  From a task this is easy with the hostvars reference, but in the inventory it returns the string "{{ hostvars['host1'].name }}" instead of the parsed value.

Sample inventory

```
servers:
  hosts:
    host1:
      name: "foo"
  
    host2:
      name: "bar"
      link: "{{ hostvars['host1'].name }}"
```

Sample play

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars['host2'].link }}"
```

Returns

```
"msg": "{{ hostvars['host1'].name }}"
```

Comment: hello, please clarify, is the name of the variable `hosts` or `hostvars`?

Comment: I updated the inventory file to show the hosts in a group.  hosts is the standard ansible key for defining inventory hosts.  hostvars is how to access variables of inventory hosts.

Answer (score -1):

Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      name: foo
    host2:
      name: bar
      link: "{{ hostvars.host1.name }}"
```

---

**Update**

Q: ***"This uses a play to expand the variables, but the question is it possible to do this inside the inventory file?"***

A: Sure. Use the module *template* and expand the variable(s) inside the inventory file. Then refresh the inventory. For example, the play below

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:

    - template:
        src: hosts
        dest: hosts
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - meta: refresh_inventory

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars.host2.link }}"
```

does this inside the inventory file

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      name: foo
    host2:
      name: bar
      link: "foo"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [template] *******************************************************************************
changed: [host1 -> localhost]

TASK [meta] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: foo
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: foo

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
host1: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Origin**

Short answer: The variables in *hostvars* are expanded on demand. You can 'instantiate' (expand) a variable in *hostvars*. For example,

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      link: "{{ link }}"
```

Details:

- The play

```yaml
- hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: link
```

gives as expected

```yaml
  link: foo
```

- But, when you take a look at *hostvars*

```yaml
- hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.host2
```

you'll find out that the variable *link* in the dictionary *hostvars* hasn't been expanded yet

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml | grep link:
  ...
  link: '{{ hostvars.host1.name }}'
```

- Let's 'instantiate' the variable first

```yaml
- hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        link: "{{ link }}"
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.host2
```

Now you'll find the variable *link* expanded in the dictionary *hostvars*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml | grep link:
  ...
  link: foo
```

- and the play

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars.host2.link }}"
```

gives expected result

```yaml
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: foo
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: foo
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: link

- hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.host2

- hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        link: "{{ link }}"
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.host2

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars.host2.link }}"
```

Comment: unfortunately this uses a play to expand the variables, but the question is it possible to do this inside the inventory file?