# How can I enforce resolution of a variable that references another variable in Ansible inventory file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, infrastructure-as-code

I can't find a solution to the following problem, although I've already read quite a lot about Ansible variables on the WWW today. I'm using Ansible v8.2.0.

My example consists of multiple files. I need to mention each file, because that may be important for the problem solution.

1. `host_vars/example1.test/vault.yml`:

   ```
   vault_network:
     vault_ipv4_address: 192.168.1.42
   ```
2. `host_vars/example1.test/vars.yml`:

   ```
   network:
     ipv4_address: "{{ vault_network['vault_ipv4_address'] }}"
   ```
3. `inventory.yml` (Ansible inventory):

   ```
   all:
     hosts:
       example1.test:
          ansible_connection: ssh
         ansible_host: "{{ hostvars['example1.test']['network']['ipv4_address'] }}"
   ```
4. `ansible_control_node.yml` (Ansible playbook):

   ```
   ---
   - name: Playbook for the 'ansible_control_node' group
     hosts: ansible_control_node
     gather_facts: true
     pre_tasks:
       - name: Debug#1 - OK
         ansible.builtin.debug:
           var: hostvars['example1.test']['network']['ipv4_address']
       - name: Debug#2 - OK
         ansible.builtin.debug:
           var: hostvars['example1.test']['ansible_connection']
       - name: Debug#3 - NOK
         ansible.builtin.debug:
           var: hostvars['example1.test']['ansible_host']
   ```

The following is the STDOUT of these tasks:

```
TASK [Debug#1 - OK] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-control-node.test] => {
    "hostvars['example1.test']['network']['ipv4_address']": "192.168.1.102"
}

TASK [Debug#2 - NOK] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-control-node.test] => {
    "hostvars['example1.test']['ansible_connection']": "ssh"
}

TASK [Debug#3 - NOK] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-control-node.test] => {
    "hostvars['example1.test']['ansible_host']": "{{ hostvars['example1.test']['network']['ipv4_address'] }}"
}
```

As you can: The 3rd task only contains the lookup expression (which has not been resolved).

Questions:

1. Why isn't `hostvars['example1.test']['ansible_host']` resolved?

   1. Is this related to recursive variable resolution (shouldn't be the case, because it works with the `vault.yml` file)?
   2. Is it because inventory files are evaluated **before** `host_vars` files (shouldn't be the case according to the documentation)?
2. Can you guide me into the right direction to solve this issue? I'd like to make the last tasks work.

I know that I could use `hostvars['example1.test']['network']['ipv4_address']` instead, but that's not the point of this question.

[How to reference another hostvar variable in an inventory file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75934381/891439) seems similar, but the difference is that the other question deals with referencing a variable declared in the same inventory file. Here I would like to reference a variable declared in `host_vars` in the inventory file.

Comment: In short: modify `inventory.yml` and change the `ansible_host` definition to `ansible_host: "{{ network.ipv4_address }}"`

Comment: @Zeitounator Well, that's a simple fix. Thank you very much!